# Parsing through command line arguments/argv

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

So I have to make a parser that parses through command line arguments that are passed into it. Below is the code that I have so far.

```
 public function parse($argv = null)
{
    $argv = $this->argsUnparsed;
    $argvs = array();
    array_shift($argvs);
    foreach($argv as $arg)
    {
            // This is supposed to find the -- characters in a string
            if(substr($arg,0,2) == '--')
            {
                    $equals = strpos($arg, '=');
                    // If character in string equals '='  saving anything before it as a key and anything afterward as a value
                    if($equals)
                    {
                            $argvs[substr($arg,2,$equals - 2)] = substr($arg,$equals + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $k = substr($arg,2);
                            if(!isset($argvs[$k]))
                            {
                                    $argvs[$k] = true;
                            }

                    }
            }
            else if(substr($arg,0,1) == '-')
            {
                    foreach(str_split(substr($arg,1)) as $k)
                    {
                            if(!isset($argvs[$k]))
                            {
                                    $argvs[$k] = true;
                            }
                            elseif($equals == false)
                            {
                                    $argvs[substr($arg,2,$equals - 2)] = substr($arg,$equals + 1);
                            }
                    }


            }
            else
            {
                    $argvs[] = $arg;
            }
    }
    return $argvs;
}
```

This is the function in which I parse the command line arguments. My problem is that when I enter "php testArgs.php -v -T 4 -l val1,val2,val3 --names=Austin,Duncan,Eddie --type=gold" it prints it out as

```
Array
(
    [0] => testArgs.php
    [v] => 1
    [T] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [l] => 1
    [2] => val1,val2,val3
    [names] => Austin,Duncan,Eddie
    [type] => gold
)
```

The second and last two array slots are perfectly correct, however the rest SHOULD be printed out as follows.

```
[T] => 4
[l] => val1,val2,val3
```

Also the first array key value pair, [0] => testArgs.php should no be shown.

Comment: For the single `-`, you are not checking for the position of an `=` but using the same `$equals` variable that you use within the `--`. Also, since you are not using an `=` sign for the `-` arguments, you would have to peek at the next argument to see if it starts with a `-` and assign that value (and skip next) or `true` if it doesn't. Plus, this would cause issues for multiple `-` arguments, so you would need to do this for just the last (or define that for it to have a value, it needs to be one character at a time). For this to work properly, I would suggest a for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: Also, what is the point of having the argument `$argv` that you pass into the function if the first thing you do in the function is overwrite it with `$this->argsUnparsed`? Either get rid of the argument to the function or lose the line that overwrites the argument and use what is passed in. I would suggest the latter simply because then your function doesn't rely on it being within that class and can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second and third `else if` blocks should be simpler.
Try something like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    // Check if a key is passed that begins with "-"
    else if(substr($arg,0,1) == '-')
     {
         $k = substr($arg,1);
         if(!isset($argvs[$k]))
         {
                 $argvs[$k] = true;
                 $previous_key = $k;
         }

     }
    // Copy the value being parsed to the previous key
    else if(!is_empty($previous_key))
    {           
        $argvs[$previous_key] = $arg;
    }

    $previous_key = "";
```

Comment: just a little confused, I only have two else if statements

Comment: My code is trying to replace your first `else if` (to check if the arg passed contains a "-") and your last `else` (to add the arg passed to the array).